# snapshot.child().exists() returning false every time even though it shouldn't

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

just coding my first app in android studio and doing some stuff with the firebase realtime database. Basically I'm trying to verify if a user has already created a username, and if not the app prompts the user to create one by re-directing them to the settings. This all works good, but the thing is that once the user has set their username and returns back to the main menu they're re-rerouted back to the settings page. I looked into it and the code keeps returning false when trying to get a snapshot of their username but I don't understand why? Thank you in advance!

Here's the code that I think isn't working in the main activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(currentUser == null){
        sendUserToLoginActivity();
    }else{
        VerifyUserExistence();
    }
}

private void VerifyUserExistence() {
    String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    RootRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Boolean Name = snapshot.child("NAME").exists();
            if(Name){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                sendUserToSettingsActivity();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here's the update settings code:

```
private void UpdateSettings() {
    String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
    String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please set your username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please set your status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
        profileMap.put("uid",currentUserID);
        profileMap.put("NAME",setUserName);
        profileMap.put("STATUS",setStatus);

    RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue(profileMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                SendUserToMainActivity();
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                String message = task.getException().toString();
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Here's the stuff in the JSON file

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "B2tdbjK9QXUVOpmH8YZgrHdy7rB2" : {
      "NAME" : "cvjjcfh",
      "STATUS" : "xvjjjhzx",
      "uid" : "B2tdbjK9QXUVOpmH8YZgrHdy7rB2"
    },
    "X685CimY11Q0HXW1haiHVIQByWW2" : {
      "NAME" : "lolinio",
      "STATUS" : "bsbsksk",
      "uid" : "X685CimY11Q0HXW1haiHVIQByWW2"
    }
  }
}
```

BTW the part of the code that always returns false is

```
snapshot.child("NAME").exists();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, please also explain to use, that exact in this code doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Boolean Name = snapshot.child("NAME").exists(); This part of the code returns false every time

Comment: Just fixed my question please try help

Comment: How do you check that? Where in your code are you logging the value?

Comment: Logging in at this bit Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Show us how is RootRef defined.

Comment: private DatabaseReference RootRef;       This is how RootRef is defined

Comment: And how is then initilized?